# Integration with respect to fractional part of $x$

Tags: integration

> Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2}(x^2+1)d\left(x-\lfloor x \rfloor\right)\;,$ Where $\lfloor x \rfloor $ represent integer part of $x$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $$I = \int_{0}^{2}(x^2+1)d\left(x-\lfloor x \rfloor\right)$$

Using Integration by parts, we get

$$I = (x^2+2)(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)|_{0}^{2}-\int_{0}^{2}2x(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)dx$$

$$I = 0-\int_{0}^{1}2x\cdot x-\int_{1}^{2}2x(x-1)dx$$

So we get $$I = -\frac{11}{3}$$

But I have seems thas value of that definite Integral must be positive.

I did not understand whats wrong in my process, Help required, Thanks

Comment: $x-[x]$ not differentiable on [0,2]

Comment: How about reading this part?? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Properties_and_relation_to_the_Riemann_integral

Comment: To frank000, can we break into $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}$ and $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{2}$ and then solve it.

Comment: To mickep would you like to explain me how can you get $\displaystyle \frac{8}{3}\;,$ Thanks